# How to wrap a plot around a circle?

Tags: plotting

Consider the code

```
a = Table[BesselJ[i, x], {i, 0, 3}]
Plot[a, {x, 0, 20}, Axes -> False]
```

producing

[image]

I'd like to transform the plot into a circle. In other words, I'd like to wrap the plot around a circle.

I found `PolarPlot[{1, 1 + 1/10 Sin[10 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` producing

[image]

which looks like a sin curve wrapped around the circle.

I know that the result would not be smooth closed, but no problem.

Comment: `c[x_] := Table[BesselJ[i, x], {i, 0, 3}]; PolarPlot[
 3 + # & /@ c[10 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: @belisarius, perfect! Since I'll use 4 colours to each graph, how to pass the colours to `PolarPlot`? I tried `PlotStyle` but no success.

Comment: Why closing vote?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update**

```
ticks[x1_, x2_] := {#/10 + π/2, #} & /@ 
  FindDivisions[{10 (x1 - π), 10 (x2 - π)}, 20]

funcs = Table[3 + BesselJ[i, 10 (x -π/2)], {i, 0, 3}];
PolarPlot[funcs // Evaluate, {x, -π/2, 3π/2}, 
    PolarAxes -> Automatic,
    PolarTicks -> {ticks[0, 2 π][[2 ;; -2]], Automatic}
] (*thanks @kguler 's and @rm-rf 's advice*)
```

> [image]

**Manipulate version**

```
Manipulate[
 funcs = Table[a BesselJ[i, 10 (x -π/2)] + b, {i, 0, n}];
 PolarPlot[funcs // Evaluate, {x, -π/2, 3π/2},
  Axes -> False] , {{n, 4}, 1, 10}, {{a, 1}, 0, 3}, {{b, 3}, 1, 5},
 ControlType -> {Automatic, VerticalSlider, VerticalSlider},
 ControlPlacement -> { Top, Left, Left}]
```

> [image]

**Original**

```
funcs = Table[3 + BesselJ[i, 10 x], {i, 0, 3}]
PolarPlot[Evaluate@funcs, {x, 0, 2 π}] (* thanks @kguler's advice *)
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: FOr v9 you need to use `PolarPlot[Evaluate@funcs, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` to get separate colors. (+1)

Comment: Nice! I'm trying to plot my graphs on a symmetric range around zero (for example, `{x,-10,10}`) and then I'd like the middle part pointing to north, that is, `f(0)` onto the vertical axis.

Comment: @Sigur Try this: `PolarPlot[funcs /. x -> y - π/2 // Evaluate, {y, 3π/2, -π/2}]`

Comment: @rm-rf, thanks. It works. The constant circle was confusing me :)

Comment: Well, if we change a little bit the domain we can do it symmetric from the north to the south.

Answer (score 16):

```
Composition[
   {#, Scale[#, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}]} &,
   Rotate[#, Pi/2, {0, 0}] &,
   First
   ] /@ Table[
   With[{root = FindRoot[D[BesselJ[i, x], x], {x, 100}][[1, 2]]},

    PolarPlot[{1 + BesselJ[i, t root/Pi]}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blend["AvocadoColors", i/15]}]
    ]
   , {i, 0, 15}] // 
 Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 500, Background -> Orange] &
```

[image]

Comment: @JunhoLee I find yours better bacause it is shorter :) Thanks, well, one could probably argue about colors :P p.s. I like the gradient in background which isn't there :)

Comment: @Kuba, amazing. Very beautiful. Since I'm doing a logo, unfortunately I can not use yours. But thanks for some idea.

Comment: [Now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kMRg9.png) I know how they designed [Amidala's hair](http://www.tfmetalsreport.com/sites/default/files/users/u3/amidala.jpg).

Comment: @Öskå It's not easy to be hairdresser there days :P

Comment: @Kuba Not to mention how hat it was during Bessel's time-frame http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Bessel#mediaviewer/File:Friedrich_Wilhelm_Bessel_%281839_painting%29.jpg